# Composite pattern: Copy tree structure

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, composite

I have implemented a basic composite pattern structure having three classes:

```
class Component
{
};

class Leaf : public Component
{
};

class Composite : public Component
{
vector<Component> Leaves;
};
```

Furthermore, I have another class ComponentCollection as a container of Components. These classes all have a corresponding class responsible for the creation of the graphical representation:

```
class GraphicComponent;
class GraphicLeaf;
class GraphicComposite; 
class GraphicComponentCollection;
```

From a given tree structure composed of different Component objects, I want to create the corresponding graphical representation objects starting from an abstract method:

```
createGraphicRepresentations(Component a_Component);
```

Is there an elegant way to create either GraphicLeaf or GraphicComposite depending on a_Component while avoiding a type check?

Comment: Java or C++? Pick one.

Comment: Note that you have slicing here (since you pick up C++): `vector<Component> Leaves`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delegate the creation of the graphical component back to the original component:

```
class Component {

    GraphicComponent create();
}
```

So you could implement a tree traverser which then calls create on every component. Thats one way. The other way is to implement a [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). With the visitor pattern your code would look something like this:

```
interface IComponentVisitor {

   void visit(Component component);
   void visit(OtherComponent component);
}

class Component {
  void accept(IComponentVisitor visitor) {
     visitor.visit(this);
  }
}
```

A concrete visitor then implements the visitor and creates the corresponding components.

```
class GraphicsVisitor {
  void visit(Component compoennt) {
  }
  void visit(OtherComponent component) {
     graphisComponent.add(new OtherGraphicsComponent());
  }
}
```